# Sorting object of arrays by values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

If I have a JavaScript object like this:

```
var data = {
 words: ["you", "me", "foo", "bar"],
 numbers: [ 160 ,   20,   100,   80]
};
```

**Is there a way to sort the properties based on value**? So that I end up with

```
var data = {
 words: ["you","foo","bar", "me" ],
 numbers: [160,   100,  80,  20]
};
```

Comment: You can make a small sorting function on the second array and apply the same change on the first array, but my question is, why do you use two arrays to associate things ? data { you:160, foo;100, ... } could do the trick right ?

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + I` (open your console), copy your `object like this` and press enter. You will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','`. This is not a valid JS object. Please, edit your question with a valid JS object

Comment: Fixed the syntax error appologies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would look like the OP wants the *"order of the words to be based on the order of the numbers"*

So to sort `words` we have to define the `weight` of each `word` accordingly by creating an object named `words_and_numbers_Mapping`. the structure looks like this

```
{"you":160,"me":20,"foo":100,"bar":80}
```

```js
var data = { words: ["you", "me", "foo", "bar"],
             numbers: [160 ,  20,  100,  80]};
             
var words_and_numbers_Mapping = data.words.reduce((acc, word, index) => {
    acc[word] = data.numbers[index];
    return acc;
}, {});
data.words.sort((a, b) => words_and_numbers_Mapping[b] - words_and_numbers_Mapping[a]);
data.numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
    words: ["you", "me", "foo", "bar"],
    numbers: [160, 20, 100, 80]
};

// Mapping data
var mData = data.words.reduce(function (op, key, index) {
    op[key] = data.numbers[index];
    return op;
}, {});

data.numbers.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; });
data.words.sort(function (a, b) { return mData[b] - mData[a]; });

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your object is not a valid object. I will modify the object to be a valid object to give you a guideline on how to solve this.

```
var data = {
 words: ["you","foo","bar", "me" ],
 numbers: [160,   100,  80,  20]
};
```

Then we can use a [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function:

```
data.words = data.words.sort();
data.numbers = data.numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

if you wouldn't like to use ES6 syntax you can do:

```
data.words = data.words.sort();
data.numbers = data.numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a - b;
})
```

Comment: I looks like the OP wants the order of the words to be based on the order of the numbers.

Comment: does the OP says it?

Comment: _"does the OP says it?"_ - Why do you think is `"bar"` after `"foo"`?

Comment: updated the syntax error appologies